# Trying to connect Laravel to Mysql via XAMPP

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp

I'm trying to get my laravel app and the mysql database in XAMPP connected and struggling. On http://localhost:8080/aws-upload/public/ I get the following error:

`` SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb2.files' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `files`) ``

It then prompts me to migrate, if I migrate on the chrome button provided by laravel the site appears and starts to work, however if I try to migrate through the terminal I get:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = mydb2 and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

I've created the database in phpMyAdmin called mydb2 and updated my .env file to:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

This is my database.php file:

```
     'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydb2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the mysql username and password?

Answer (score 0):

In your database.php file:

`'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),` try changing localhost to `127.0.0.1`

In your .env file:

At the top of the file, you'll see it says `APP_URL=http://example.com` - change the url to `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1`